# VueJS: router.resolve issue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

A warning is shown in the console:

> the id param was not provided.

The docs mention that the current route will be used:

> **current** is the current Route by default (most of the time you don't
>   need to change this)

html code:

```
<div id="app">
  <router-link to="/5">/5</router-link>
  <button @click="onClick">Resolve</button>
</div>
```

js code:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',

  router: new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {
        name: 'foo',
        path: '/:id',
        component: {
            template: '<div>Foo <router-view/></div>',
        },
        children: [
            {
            name: 'bar',
            path: 'bar',
            component: {
                template: '<div>Bar</div>'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
    ],
  }),

  methods: {
    onClick() {
      console.log('Omitting current');
        this.$router.resolve({ name: 'bar' });
      console.log('Including current');
        this.$router.resolve({ name: 'bar' }, this.$route);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: The documentation is frustratingly sparse re what that `current` parameter actually affects. My guess is you just need to explicitly provide the id param in the route object: `this.$router.resolve({ name: 'bar', params: { id: this.$route.params.id } })`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is overdue, but I'll share what I found.

When you call `$router.resolve()`, it uses `vue-router/src/util/location.js`'s `normalizeLocation()` to get the `Location` object.

And you can see there that the `current?` option is only used to resolve relative paths.

The only case where `current.params` is included in the new `Location` is when the given `RawLocation` is relative, and includes `params` itself.